# javascript array loop create element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create li elements based on the number of values in array.
Basically, for every key in an array an li element needs to be created.

```
<ul class="alpharow">
</ul>
    $(".alpharow").each(function() {

    var alpha = new Array();
        alpha['this'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
        alpha['that'] = ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'];
     var n = alpha.length;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            //$("li:eq(" + i + ")");

           var li_tag = '<li class="alpha_li"></li>';
        }

        $(".alpharow").append(li_tag);

        //$("span").text("There are " + n + " kys.");

    });
```

So, a, b, c etc...would all have their own `<li>`

Thanks for the help, let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: I suggest stepping back and reading some good tutorials or books on JavaScript. I found *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* by David Flanagan quite good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have array of arrays. If you need to create LIs for all of them use such sample:

```
$(".alpharow").each(function() {

    var alpha = new Array();
    alpha['this'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
    alpha['that'] = ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'];

    // go thru the main array
    for (var key in alpha) {
        // go thru the inner arrays
        var arr = alpha[key];
        for (i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
            //apped LI's
            $(".alpharow").append($('<li></li>', { class: 'alpha_li', text: arr[i] }));
        }
    }       
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/m8vwz/1/

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues there:

- This code in the loop serves no purpose: `$("li:eq(" + i + ")");`
- Move your `$(".alpharow").append(li_tag);` *into* the loop (but don't do the lookup each time, cache the result of `$(".alpharow")` in a variable at the top, before calling `each`, and then reuse it).
- Your `alpha` is an `Array` to which you're adding no *elements*. (*Array elements* in JavaScript terminology are properties in the array object with names consisting entirely of numerals.) You're adding a couple of properties to it, but they're not elements, so `length` will be `0`.
- The *values* of the two properties you have added are each arrays, so you need to loop through *them*.

Answer (score 1):

It all stems from how you're handling the array. In JS array's don't have defined key names, instead you'd use an object, so this code works:

```
var alpha = { };
alpha['this'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
alpha['that'] = ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'];

$.each(alpha, function() {
    $.each(this, function() {

        var li_tag = '<li class="alpha_li">' + this + '</li>';

        $(".alpharow").append(li_tag);
    });
});
```

`alpha` is changed to an object and we set `this` and `that` keys. We then use jQuery's `$.each()` to loop though the top object and then through each key to get to our array and then add them as `li` elements.

Comment: *"In JS array's don't have defined key names"* They do, in fact. Arrays are objects *plus* array-like behavior. It's true that he's not using the `alpha` object as an array, though.

Comment: That's just splitting hairs now ;)

Comment: `@Ahmed`: :-) I don't think so, though -- I use the fact that arrays are true objects and so can have arbitrary, non-element properties quite frequently (usually when I'm cross-indexing them).